# Press any key to play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity, and I'm trying to build a menu to a game, but I can't seem to be able to use a key press to activate the button.

```
public class MenuCamControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform currentMount;
    public float speed = 0.1f;
    public float zoom = 0.1f;   

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, currentMount.position, speed);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, currentMount.rotation, speed);
        
    }

    public void SetMount(Transform newMonut)
    {
       
               currentMount = newMonut;
              
    }
}
```

[image]

Edit: I added the code I have right now, which is a animation.

Edit2: This is where the animation leads [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h03iP.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Input.anyKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKey.html) and a flag to determine when the first key is pressed to not trigger it multiple times.

```
public class Example: MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool keyPressed = false;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKey && !keyPressed)
        {
             keyPressed = true; 
        }
        else
        {
                // put your camera move code here 
        }
    }
}
```

This method also picks up any mouse input as well. If you truly just want any keyboard input and not any mouse input to continue I can update my answer.

You do not need a UI button for this. Just a function to track if an input occurs and another to handle starting or loading your game. If you want the game to start when a button is clicked, you would just need to assign the onClick listener to a function either in code or in the inspector.

If you add what code you'd like to run or what you'd like to do after the click I can update my snippet.

**Edit:** Here is how you would combine my snippet and your current code. You can also use a `Coroutine`, but it is not needed.

```
public class MenuCamControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform currentMount;
    public float speed = 0.1f;
    public float zoom = 0.1f;  
    
    private bool keyPressed = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKey && !keyPressed)
        {
             keyPressed = true; 
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, currentMount.position, speed);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, currentMount.rotation, speed);
        }
    }

    // I am not sure what this does, it currently is not called?
    public void SetMount(Transform newMonut)
    {
       currentMount = newMonut;      
    }
}
```

With a `Coroutine`, it could look something like

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.anyKey && !keyPressed)
    {
        keyPressed = true; 
        
        if(referenceToCoroutine == null)
            referenceToCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DoCameraAnimation());
    }
}

private IEnumerator DoCameraAnimation()
{
    ...   
}
```

You would need to change your current camera animation slightly to work in a `Coroutine`.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet of code I'm doing a moving camera animation, how do I add it to your code ? I'll edit my question with the snippet of code.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now so it is harder to edit code. You can either put it in the `else if` block or call a `Coroutine` that does your camera movement inside of the `if` conditional. Is this menu screen animation going to end to load your game? Or is your game in the same scene as your menu?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I'm from Portugal and it was alright pretty late, I added a new picture, the snippet of code still doesn't work... Where should I put the code file? inside the button or canvas?

Comment: All this code will do is start your animation when any input is detected. After that you'll need to hook up your 3 buttons. The script needs to be on any object. Are you setting your mount? Has your animation ever worked?

Comment: I figured out the problem, I have the animation set to the button fuction "onClick" so I have to simulate the button being clicked. I used something like this... if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(this.gameObject);
        }

Comment: Now it works but I have to press it twice so I'm trying to figure it out how to make it once only

Comment: Use the second snippet I posted, the one directly after the edit. The animation should play with any buttons and will play on a single key press or click.

Comment: The way I made it work was on a seperate script, without the animation on it. how would it work ??

Comment: I'm very confused as to what your question is. If all you want to do is run your animation after you click any key, the script I provided does that. If you want to click any of the three buttons in your second screenshot, you need to assign onClicks to those.