# How to make the if statement wait for enough time until I press any key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a "press any key to continue" function for my level completed screen (which obviously appears after successfully finishing a level), but after level finishing level, I have very little time to press a key (almost immediately), otherwise it just doesn't read my key input. How can I fix this? Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
            if (Input.anyKey)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
                Debug.Log("...");
            }
    }
}
```

I expected it to behave in a way that it would not do anything until I press any key and only then then it would execute the code inside the if statement. But instead, it is very impatient and almost instantaneously skips the if statement after I call the `LoadNextLevel()` method. Sorry for the word salad.

I looked up for the solutions on the internet but almost all of them uses `void Update()` to begin with. Is there a way to solve the problem without using `Update()`?

If there is not how can I use `Update()` in that scenario?

Edit: It is working now! Here is the final version.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isReadyForNextLevel = false;

    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
         isReadyForNextLevel = true;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (!isReadyForNextLevel) 
           return;

        if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
            Debug.Log("...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use that but i had to restart unity everytime i use it,  i guess it somehow stucked in a loop.

Comment: There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840841/press-any-key-to-play) on how to do it in the update method.

Comment: I've seen this but i don't really know how to apply this to my code tbh since i think changing LoadNextLevel() to Update() might break the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ReadyForNextLevel()` only once the level is finished and you want to wait for the player's indication to continue

```
public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isReadyForNextLevel = false;

    public void ReadyForNextLevel()
    {
        isReadyForNextLevel = true;
    }
    
    public void Update()
    {
        if (!isReadyForNextLevel) return;
        
        if (Input.anyKey)
        {
        
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
            Debug.Log("...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that method must have a return type.

Comment: After typing `void` before the `Update()` it worked , thank you!